# Using Deedle with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, deedle

Is it possible to use Deedle if I'm stuck with .NET 4.0, VS 2010 and Windows 7?

Currently it's complaing that I need FSharp.Core 4.3, but I only have 4.0 available.

Maybe an older version of Deedle somewhere?

I have to replace some scripts that use Python Pandas with C#.

Comment: How about upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 Pro? It's free although they call it Community Edition now

Comment: Sadly not possible, it's for work. I'm really stuck with 2010.

Comment: I think this may change if management understands that you won't be able to use most processing libraries out there, especially any that's using F#. As for Deedle, the project is barely two years old, don't expect VS 2010 support. You could try forking the source from Github and backporting it to VS 2010 but that would probably cost your company more than buying VS *Ultimate* (expected man-months *your-salary*3). 3 is a guesstimate of what the company needs to *gain* from your work to justify its cost: What you cost + what the company would earn if you did some other job.